# PHP Curl CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS alternative for node.js

Tags: php, node.js, fetch

I'm looking for a way to interact with a form before submitting a POST like the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS option for PHP curl provides, but with node.js.

I'm rewriting some PHP code to javascript, and it's the following line I can't find a javascript alternative for

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"rememberMe": true}');
```

I'm currently using the `node-fetch` NPM library

My javascript code so far

```
fetch(requestUrl,
  {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
  }
)
```

with the headers including content-type and authorization

Comment: What does your JavaScript code look like?

Comment: It looks a lot better as an edit to your question.

Comment: It also helps if you explain which Node libraries you're using as `fetch` could mean a number of things.

Comment: There we go! Thanks for helping with the formatting

Comment: Have a look at [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) and in particular the `body:` option. See the "Post with JSON" example.

Comment: @tadman, make an answer and I'll make it as the answer - for some reason I had totally misunderstood the way it worked

Comment: It'd be better if you fixed it, confirmed it was working, and added a self-answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87189/tadman) the answer was found at https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#post-with-json

By providing a body you can achieve the desired result

Final code would look like the following if JSON is the desired way to go

```
fetch(requestUrl,
    {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({'rememberMe': 'true'}),
        headers: headers
    }
)
```